# JQuery UI Dialog not closing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I am using JQuery dialog to render partial view.

Scenario :

Step 1: Click on 'Add' anchor link, dialog with text box will open.

Step 2: User fills text box values and click on save button.

Step 3: Details will be saved and dialog will be closed.

Step 4: Now User will click on 'View' anchor link , again dialog with read-only text box values will open.

Step 5: User will click on cancel button.

Step 6: Again user click on 'Add' anchor link, and dialog with text box open.

Step 7: User fills text box values and click on save button.

Step 8: **The problem starts from here**. it should save details which user has entered just now, but it is saving old values (which we have viewed in step 4).

I have tried below code to render partial view on click and open dialog

```
var div = $("#DivTaskDetail");
var Title = "";

if (Mode == 1) {
    Title = "Edit Task Detail";
}
else if (Mode == 2) {
    Title = "View Task Detail";
}
else {
    Title = "Add Task Detail";
}

div.load("/Task/TaskDetailEditView?taskID=" + TaskID + "&mode=" + Mode, function () {
    div.dialog({
        modal: true,
        width: 500,
        height: 450,
        title: Title,
        resizable: false,
        close: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");               
        }
    });
});
```

and on click of cancel button, i have written below code

```
function onClickCancelTask() {  
$('#DivTaskDetail').dialog("close");
}
```

I have tried below different codes to close dialog, but none of are working fine for me.

```
1. $('#DivTaskDetail').empty();

2. $('#DivTaskDetail').remove();

3. $('#DivTaskDetail').dialog('destroy').remove();

4. $('.ui-icon-closethick').click();

5. $('#DivTaskDetail').dialog("close");

6. $('#DivTaskDetail').dialog("destroy");

7. $("#DivTaskDetail").dialog("destroy");
   $('#DivTaskDetail').dialog('close').dialog('remove'); 

8. $('#DivTaskDetail').dialog("destroy");
   $('#DivTaskDetail').remove();
```

can anyone please guide me on this.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the work around and it's working fine for me.

I have used below code to open Partial View as a JQuery dialog.

```
 var div = $("#DivTaskDetail");
var Title = "";

if (Mode == 1) {
    Title = "Edit Task Detail";
}
else if (Mode == 2) {
    Title = "View Task Detail";
}
else {
    Title = "Add Task Detail";
}

$.ajax({
    url: "/Task/TaskDetailEditView",
    type: "Post",
    datatype: "html",
    data: { "taskID": TaskID, "mode": Mode },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#DivTaskDetail').html(data);            

        $("#DivTaskDetail").dialog({
            autoopen: false,
            width: 500,
            height: 450,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            draggable: true,
            title: Title,
            open: function () {
                $('div.ui-widget-overlay').hide();
                $("div.ui-dialog").not(':first').remove();
            }
        });

        $('a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').remove();
        $('#divProcessImage').css({ "display": "none" });
    },
    error: function (req, status, error) {
        ErrorMessage(req.responseText);
        $('#screen').css({ "display": "block", "width": "", "height": "" });
        $('#divProcessImage').css({ "display": "none" });
    }
});
```

and on click of close button, i am using below code.

```
    $('#DivTaskDetail').dialog("destroy");
    $('#DivTaskDetail').html("");
```